# How to execute specific code when a window changed position?

Tags: windows, tcl, tk-toolkit

I would like to execute specific code when a window has been moved by the user clicking the window title decoration and dragging the mouse to a new position.

The command "wm protocol window ?name? ?command?" is used to manage window manager messages like WM_DELETE_WINDOW.
Trying the following code doesn't do anything when the window has been moved..

```
package require Tk

wm title . "move test"
wm protocol . WM_MOVE {puts "window has been moved!"}
```

It seems Tk doesn't know about the message WM_MOVE so it ignores it.
However catching the WM_DELETE_WINDOW message instead of WM_MOVE the above code works.

Am I missing something?
Is there another way to programmatically react on the change of a window's position?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Window positions should be reported via conventional events, i.e., `<Configure>` events. Try doing:

```
bind . <Configure> {puts x=%x,y=%y,width=%w,height=%h}
```

Then move and resize the `.` window; you should see events for each of these actions. Note that the events do not necessarily mean a move; a resize will also generate them. As with any binding on a toplevel, you should take care that it isn't being reported for one of its sub-widgets (look at `%W` to work that out). You may find that `%X` and `%Y` are better than `%x` and `%y`; experiment…